# Python 3.x pandas how to compare duplicates and drop the rows with the higher values in csv?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, duplicates

Hi I'm new to python and currently using python version 3.x. I have a very large set of data needed to be filtered in csv. I searched online and many recommended loading it into pandas DataFrame (done).

My columns can be defined as: "ID", "Name", "Time", "Token", "Text"

I need to check under "Token" for any duplicates - which can be done via

> df = df[df.Token.duplicate(keep=False)]

(Please correct me if I am wrong)

But the problem is, I need to keep the original row while dropping the other duplicates. For this, I was told to compare it with "Time". The "Time" with the smallest value will be original (keep) while drop the rest of the duplicates.

For example:

> ID  Name  Time  Token   Text
>
> 1 | John | 333 | Hello | xxxx
>
> 2 | Mary | 233 | Hiiii | xxxx
>
> 3 | Jame | 222 | Hello | xxxx
>
> 4 | Kenn | 555 | Hello | xxxx

Desired output:

> 2 | Mary | 233 | Hiiii | xxxx
>
> 3 | Jame | 222 | Hello | xxxx

What I have done:

```
    ##compare and keep the smaller value
    def dups(df):
       return df[df["Time"] < df["Time"]]

df = df[df.Token.duplicate()].apply(dups)
```

This is roughly where I am stuck! Can anyone help? Its my first time coding in python, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Token'], keep='first')`

Comment: Is order important here? If not, you can sort on `Time`... and then `drop_duplicates` is guaranteed to keep the smallest rows.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Hellooo, thank you for fast reply, erm but as far as I know (I maybe wrong) keep='first' is keeping the first entry, but I have thousand of row and the "time" are all recorded in random, so the first entry may have a higher value instead, is there a way to compare it (based on their "time") ? so I can keep the smaller value

Comment: Like I mentioned, you can do `df = df.sort_values('Time').drop_duplicates('Time', keep='first')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sort_values` + `drop_duplicates`:

```
df = df.sort_values('Time')\
        .drop_duplicates('Token', keep='first').sort_index()
df

   ID  Name  Time  Token  Text
1   2  Mary   233  Hiiii  xxxx
2   3  Jame   222  Hello  xxxx
```

The final `sort_index` call restores order to your original dataframe. If you want to retrieve a monotonically increasing index beyond this point, call `reset_index`.